# Search the customized listview always open the first item using OnQueryTextListener in fragment

Tags: android

This my code :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_mainMenu3);

    item.setVisible(false);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().setTitle("DASHBOARD");

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener textChangeListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // this is your adapter that will be filtered
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                System.out.println("on text chnge text: " + newText);
                return true;
            }

            LOding the adapter code
            adapter = new FavouritesAdapter(getContext(), distanceArr, contactName, status, leadDetailsId, addressLine1, addressLine2, city, state, zipCode);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

when I search the item through the action bar it filters on first position in list it does not show any list view in android studio

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<YourItemDataModel> { ...` and override its `onBind()` and `matches()` methods

Comment: class FavouritesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {} This adapter class i have add aldready

Comment: yes i know, and this is not working, so you need another adapter

Comment: another adapter means ??? can u explain